# Need some help creating JSON from loop and not formatted correctly

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to create a Python script to create a JSON from a text file with data.

```
taskCount = 0

while (taskCount < 5):
        stock = {
                "serial": serial[counter],
                "price": price[counter],
             },
        taskCount += 1
        with open('tasks.json', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(stock, outfile)
    counter += 1
```

It just shows up as

```
[{"serial": "1", "price": "1"}][{"serial": "2", "price": "2"}][{"serial": "3", "price": "3"}][{"serial": "4", "price": "4"}][{"serial": "5", "price": "5"}]
```

I would like it to show up as

```
[{"serial": "1", "price": "1"},{"serial": "2", "price": "2"},{"serial": "3", "price": "3"},{"serial": "4", "price": "4"},{"serial": "5", "price": "5"}]
```

Each entry separated with , and there is no []'s on each besides the beginning and end. I think I'm on the right track, but maybe there's an easy way to do this?

EDIT: Fixed code if anyone else had this issue

```
myList = []
taskCount = 0

while (taskCount < 5):
        stock = {
                "serial": serial[counter],
                "price": price[counter],
             },
        taskCount += 1
        myList.append(stock)
    counter += 1
with open('tasks.json', 'a') as outfile:
     json.dump(myList, outfile)
```

Comment: You should append each ‘stock’ to a list and finally write the list as json to the file once at the end.

Comment: That worked. Thank you!